# Oracle XmlQuery to retrieve the path of the node

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath

I am having the below xml and I am having trouble to get the LocationOfNode using xmlquery. Any suggestions how to proceed? Please see the below example to see what I am trying to achieve.

```
 <data>
    <type id="01" desc="Doctors">
         <type id="02" desc="Private Hospital">
             <type id="03" desc="John"></type>
             <type id="04" desc="James"></type>
        </type>
        <type id="05" desc="Public Hospital">
            <type id="06" desc="Jacob"></type>
            <type id="07" desc="Joseph"></type>
        </type>
   </type>
   <type id="08" desc="Actors">
         ........
   </type>
 </data>
```

Example:

If My Input is:07

Expected output is : Doctors/Public Hospital/Joseph

I am trying to use the below xmlpath with xmlquery

```
SELECT XMLQuery(
'//*[@id="07"]/ancestor::*[@id="01"][1]'
PASSING MYXMLClob RETURNING CONTENT
) "myXMLQuery"
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your expected output, it looks like you're trying to validate your xpath based on the result you get back from it. In this case, you already know the expected location and want to verify the absolute path to it, but in regards to only the `desc` attribute.

XPath isn't really designed to return the path for valid queries, so it would be much easier to use something other in that regard. However, if you are stuck using XPath, you could apply a workaround like so:

```
substring(concat(//*[@id='07']/../../@desc, '/', //*[@id='07']/../@desc, '/', //*[@id='07']/@desc), 0, number(boolean(count(//*[@id='07']))) * string-length(concat(//*[@id='07']/../../@desc, '/', //*[@id='07']/../@desc, '/', //*[@id='07']/@desc))+1)
```

But I wouldn't suggest this for dynamic/complex queries.